# Formula field error on custom objects

Tags: formula

im getting error on below logic

```
IF(RecordType.Name== 'Purchase Order',  Name='po-'CC_OrderNumber__c- CC_Sales_Order__r.CC_OrderNumber__c ,
Name ='so-'CC_OrderNumber__c - C_Project__r.Name )
```

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number,
>   Date, DateTime, received Text

Comment: im getting error on below logicIF(RecordType.Name== 'Purchase Order', Name ='po-'+CC_OrderNumber__c-CC_Sales_Order__r.CC_OrderNumber__c ,
 Name ='so-'+CC_OrderNumber__c-CC_Project__r.Name )Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Text

Comment: If i understood, your setting up name to something  if record type is purchase order. This can be done by using workflow but not formula field

Comment: What is the return type of the formula and what is the purpose of the field? Just putting in a formula does not give us enough to help you. See - [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a concatenation operator in several places

```
IF(RecordType.Name== 'Purchase Order',  
   Name='po-' & CC_OrderNumber__c & '-' & CC_Sales_Order__r.CC_OrderNumber__c ,
   Name ='so-' & CC_OrderNumber__c & '-' &  C_Project__r.Name )
```